# ubuntu Installation does Not detect second hard drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I Have 2 sata Hard drives

1 TB and a 500 GB

i created another partition on 500gb hard drive but in ubuntu installation i cant see the partition i made only the hard drive and detects it like this :

size: 467Gb Free space : unknown

[image]

Comment: did you formated it as ext4 ?

Comment: ubuntu does not detects the drive K so im not able to format as Ext4

Comment: so format it as NTFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've formatted the second drive as Dynamic - the NTFS-3G module in Ubuntu will not read these correctly.

Reformat the drive as basic and it should pick up. Note that you will lose all data on the drive doing it. You can convert from basic to dynamic without data loss, but not the other way around.

Also, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble by formatting the volumes as FAT. NTFS support in Linux, while greatly improved, is still reliant on reverse engineering Microsoft's code. FAT, more or less, Just Works.

Comment: you mean i should format the hole disk or just drive (k) 33GB ?

Comment: The entire thing (Disk 1). Dynamic vs basic is set on the disk level, rather than the volume/partition level.

Comment: You cannot install Ubuntu to any Windows created partitions whether FAT or NTFS. You have to have Linux formatted partitions like ext4 which Windows cannot create. Generally NTFS is fine now. FAT32 does have other limits like no journal and 4GB file limit. So FAT32 is ok for smaller partitions, but not recommended for larger ones. Then NTFS works better.